# How to get time adjusted to user timezone in Sitecore CMS

Tags: timezone, sitecore

I'm using custom command to import data for newly created item in Sitecore. Since there is a lot of data importing, this process is in the background. I send an email with import status once it is completed. I am able to get email from UserProfile:

```
User currentUser = Sitecore.Context.User;
UserProfile currentProfile = currentUser.Profile;
```

The problem is that we have **import starting time** in the email. Since I haven't find where the user time zone is stored, I can't adjust it to match the user time zone.

Do you happen to know if there is any setting to define user time zone from the C# code?

P.S. In the bottom right corner there is a correct time adjusted for the current user, but I didn't find any information on how and where it stored

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's stored (in fact I believe Sitecore stores DateTime relative to the CM server and not the client).

For you to have an accurate timezone for the visitor/customer, you'd need to either ask for it directly (registration prompt or user profile option) or look it up using Geo data from the originating ip (though with VPNs and public access points this becomes increasingly less reliable).

My suggestion would be to store the start time in UTC and (if necessary) let the user know it was started at that time. If a time elapsed is required, perform the calculation before sending the email off--since start time and end time are relative to the server anyways, just let them know it took "5min 30sec" to complete. If they receive the email at 5:08pm (email timestamp) they can do some simple match and assume it was started at 5:03 (or thereabouts).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the time in the bottom right of the Desktop is using the users local system time (most likely using JavaScript) so it is not dependent on their Sitecore user profile.

There doesn't appear to be any timezone information stored against the user profile, the best you can get the is the CultureInfo based on the `Regional ISO Code`, although this still is not truly accurate for countries with multiple timezones (USA, Canada, Russia, Australia etc).

You could extend the [User Profile to add custom properties](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/sitecore-users-custom-profile-properties/) and store a timezone field, but it is not available by default.

My suggestion would be to list the start time in UTC time, and let the user mentally adjust to their own timezone. This is what I have done previously, esp since servers themselves could be located in any location.